# passing in a list of variables in a for loop function

Tags: r, list, function, factors

I have a list of variable names in a vector that I want to pass through into a function, take those dataframes from the output and use as the parameters for the function in the next iteration of the loop.

```
standardized_funct= function(train,test, my_variable) {

  #handle missing values
   train$my_variable =  ifelse(is.na(train$my_variable)==TRUE, 'MISSING',my_variable)

   my_variable=eval(substitute(my_variable))

  # handle missing values and set factors equivalent
  test$my_variable = ifelse(is.na(test$my_variable)==TRUE, 'MISSING',my_variable)
    test$my_variable = factor(test$my_variable, levels = base::unique(train$my_variable))


  train$my_variable = 
     factor(train$my_variable)

  output_factors = list(TRAIN = train, TEST = test)
  return(output_factors)
}   


   # setup dummy data
   rm(mtcars)
    mtcars2 = rbind(mtcars,mtcars)
   list_of_var = c("hp","mpg",'cyl')

  for (each_variable in list_of_var){

outputdf =  standardized_funct(train = mtcars, test = mtcars2, my_variable = each_variable

mtcars = outputdf$TRAIN
mtcars2 = outputdf$TEST
  # should loop through each variable and run the function...that transforms the values to factor
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This seems like an overly-complicated approach.

Comment: If you change all of your `train$my_variable` to `train[[my_variable]]` it will accept a string so you can do what you want.

Comment: @runningbirds seriously I didn't understand your problem! Could you give a small example of your input and what you output should be.?

Comment: I want to ensure that I have common factor levels throughout two different dataframes.   (Sometimes a dataframe my contain a value that the other doesn't have).       I have a list of these variables that I want to pass through (i guess using a for loop) or any better way.